# How to find an object created by own class?

Tags: matlab, class, oop, object, find

I created an object in MATLAB by using my own class `my_class` like this

```
car = my_class();
```

with

```
classdef my_class < handle

   properties
       color = 'red';
   end

   methods
      function obj = my_class()
          % ...
      end
   end
end
```

Now I am trying to find my object by its class (`my_class`) or by properties (`color`). But `findall` or `findobj` always return an empty matrix, whatever I am doing. Do you have any clue? Thanks.

**EDIT** I need something like this:

```
car1 = my_classA();
car2 = my_classA();
house1 = my_classB(); ... house25 = my_classB();
tree1 = my_classC(); ... tree250 = my_classC();
```

In my code, I can not refer to the names of the handles (like `car2.color`), because I have many different objects and I want to search for them by a function, that looks like the following one:

```
loop over all objects (maybe with findobj/findall without knowing object name/handle)
    if object is of class `my_classA`
        get handle of `my_classA`
        change `color`
    else if object is of class `my_classB`
        get handle of `my_classB`
        do something ...
    end
end
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What's your use case?

Comment: I need to change properties or need to call methods for serveral objects. But I need to search for the specified objects first in some kind of a loop or similar, because I want to get the objects by theis values, not by their handles.

Comment: ...but why don't you collect those objects in an array then?

Comment: ...this is starting to [smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). I think I have a hunch of what is going on here...

Comment: Ah, okay, I tried your advice by collecting all objects in an array. This does indeed work so far. Thanks. But I would also like a different approch by looking for all objects by there class first. I tried `h = findall(0,'class','my_classA')` and similar things, but everyting returns an empty-matrix.

Comment: You're probably looking for something along the lines of `A = whos(); B = A(strcmp({A.class}, 'my_classA')); B.name`, but well, that's just going to lead to `eval` and all sorts of other inefficient ugliness...which is what I'm trying to steer you away from  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want this:

```
% Create example array of objects
A(20) = object;
[A([3 14 17]).color] = deal('blue');

% Get those objects which are red, and change to orange
[A(strcmp({A.color}, 'red')).color] = deal('orange');
```

I have to admit, `findobj` would have been much better to read. <strike>But that only works on graphics handles as far as I'm aware, so you'd have to overload it for your class.</strike>

And that overloaded function, would contain something similar to this.

**EDIT** as noted by Navan, this works:

```
B = findobj(A, 'color', 'red');
[B.color] = deal('orange');
```

seems to be faster than the `strcmp` method, too.

Comment: findobj should work fine in this case. B = findobj(A, 'color', 'red'); [B.color] = deal('orange'); findobj works for handle classes as long as you pass the handles as first input.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not exactly, what I was looking for. I need something that (first) loops over all own objects (without using or knowing the handle of the object) and then (second) gets the handle of the specific object.

Comment: @Lemonbonbon ...and why can't you do that with the code I've provided? Perhaps you're looking for the function `isa()`? If this is still not what you're looking for, can you please edit in your exact goal, with example input and  expected outcomes.